# ZipException when running junit tests

Tags: java, exception, ant, junit, classpath

I've been trying in vain to get ant to execute some tests written in junit. Any advice would be much appreciated. I'm pretty new to both ant and Java so please be patient.

As a quick summary, what i'm doing is trying to get ant to execute a very simple test, the classpath looks ok considering the output from ant -debug. I'm getting a null test error for a test who's class file is explicitly mentioned in the classpath. Also, i'm getting a ZipException, i dont know what that's about.

Here's a testcase i'm trying to run:

```
package testmanagment;
import junit.framework.*;

public abstract class EasyTest extends TestCase
{

    public EasyTest(String name)
    {
        super(name);
    }

    protected void setUp()
    {}

    protected void testSeeMee() throws Exception
    {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    protected void testSeeMeetoo() throws Exception
    {
        assertTrue(true);
    }   
}
```

There are a few tests in the package, this one was just to see why everything was failing. it fails with ZipException.

and here's a little bit of my make file:

```
  <property name="src" value="src/"/> 
     <property name="build" value="build/"/>  
     <property name="test" value="${build}test/"/>
     <property name="testreportsdir" value="${test}reports/"/>
     <property name="classdir" value="${build}classes/"/>
     <property name="lib" value="lib/"/> 

    <path id="files-classpath">  
        <fileset dir="lib/" >  
            <include name="*.jar"/>  
        </fileset>  
    </path> 

    <path id="tests-classpath">
        <path refid="files-classpath"/>
        <pathelement location="${classdir}/"/>
    </path>

    <path id="tests-runpath">
        <path refid="tests-classpath"/>
        <fileset dir="${test}/">
            <include name="*.class"/>
            <include name="**/*.class"/>
            <include name="testmanagment/*.class"/>
            <include name="*.*"/>
            <include name="**/*.*"/>
            <include name="testmanagment/*.*"/>
        </fileset>
        </path>

blah blah blah

    <target name="test" depends="compile_tests">
        <junit haltonfailure="true"  printsummary="false">
            <classpath refid="tests-runpath"/>
            <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
            <test name="testmanagment.EasyTest"/>
            <test name="testmanagment.TestUser"/>
            <test name="testmanagment.TestTest"/>
                </junit>
    </target>
```

ant compiles everything fine, and looks to put everything in the right places. but it cant seem to find my tests... here's a little piece of what ant spat out when i ran it with the -debug option.

```
 [junit] Using CLASSPATH /host/Users/Sheena/Desktop/School/Software dev/lab_project/lib/junit-4.8.1.jar:/host/Users/Sheena/Desktop/School/Software dev/lab_project/lib/sqlitejdbc-v056.jar:/host/Users/Sheena/Desktop/School/Software dev/lab_project/build/classes:/host/Users/Sheena/Desktop/School/Software dev/lab_project/build/test/testmanagment/EasyTest.class:/host/Users/Sheena/Desktop/School/Software dev/lab_project/build/test/testmanagment/TestTest.class:/host/Users/Sheena/Desktop/School/Software dev/lab_project/build/test/testmanagment/TestUser.class:/usr/share/ant/lib/junit.jar:/usr/share/java/ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar
Class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.BriefJUnitResultFormatter loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Finding class testmanagment.EasyTest
Ignoring Exception java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file reading resource testmanagment/EasyTest.class from /host/Users/Sheena/Desktop/School/Software dev/lab_project/build/test/testmanagment/EasyTest.class
Ignoring Exception java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file reading resource testmanagment/EasyTest.class from /host/Users/Sheena/Desktop/School/Software dev/lab_project/build/test/testmanagment/TestTest.class
Ignoring Exception java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file reading resource testmanagment/EasyTest.class from /host/Users/Sheena/Desktop/School/Software dev/lab_project/build/test/testmanagment/TestUser.class
    [junit] Testsuite: testmanagment.EasyTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit] 
    [junit] Null Test:  Caused an ERROR
```

sorry about the ugly output there, it's all i have to work with for now.

it looks very much like the testcases are in the classpath, so i dont know what's happening... Maybe it's something to do with the ZipException but i dont know...

Comment: What tools are you using? Are you using any IDE with ANT plugin such as Netbeans or Eclipse? They should generate warnings if paths are wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You added `EasyTest.class` as a JAR file to the classpath. This doesn't work. Class files aren't JAR archives, so the classloader throws an error when it tries to load classes from it.

Comment: No, i used: <include name="testmanagment/*.class"/> to include all the .class files unless there is somewhere else i should state it also? it looks like ant knows it's a .class

Comment: You must not add class files to the classpath. Only add the directory which contains the packages. That is if your class is `testmanagment.EasyTest`, add the folder which **contains** `testmanagment/` because Java will add the package name to the search path.

Comment: i've tried using a fileset,  that gives me the zipexception no matter if i use *.class or just the directory. And i've tried similar pathelement stuff but then it just cant find the file. Gosh darnit, this it getting a little old. It has to be a typo, i just cant find it.

Comment: Don't use `fileset`, use `<pathelement location="${classdir}"/>`

Comment: At the moment i'm using:  <path id="tests-runpath">
  <pathelement location="${test}testmanagment/"/>
  <path refid="tests-classpath"/> </path> tests-classpath is what i used to compile the tests, and they go to ${test}testmanagment/ when they comiple

Comment: Yes but you also tell Java to look in the package `testmanagment`, so when you run the code, the Java runtime will try to load `${test}testmanagment/testmanagment` which doesn't exist. Just add `${test}` to the classpath and it will work.

Comment: You rock my world Aaron! I thought that since i had to add the path to the actual .class files, not to the package they were in. Thank you for your patience in helping me out, this thing's been driving me nuts :)

Comment: You're welcome. :-) Almost all Java beginners fall into this stupid trap :-( So it would be great if Oracle fixed it (for example by providing a better error message like "did you mean ${test} instead of ...")

Comment: `<dirset>` also works here where fileset fails, when you're adding dirs to the classpath (but path/pathelement is more 'modern')

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're running jUnit 3. You may want to try creating a TestCase class that isn't abstract class. Also, have a default constructor or else jUnit won't know how to create the test class.

In your case it should be:

```
package testmanagment; 

import junit.framework.*;

public class EasyTest extends TestCase {

    public EasyTest() {
        super("Easy Test");
    }

    public void setUp() {
    }

    public void testSeeMee() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    public void testSeeMeetoo() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(true);
    }   
}
```

Comment: i'm using 3.8.2 specifically. Taking out the abstract keyword doesn't change anything

Comment: how about removing the constructor?