# Junit - Ant - Soap UI and Data File

Tags: ant, junit, soapui

I am trying to run a basic REST Web Service Test calling a Soap UI project from JUnit in ANT.

Everything compiles correctly and runs, however when I try to run a test that uses an external data file I get the error:

> Unable to obtain resource from C:\soapTest\atmTest3.csv:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
>       [junit] Unable to obtain resource from C:\soapTest\atmTest3.csv:

I have already searched and seen others who have had the problem with classes and tried to only include what I believe I need.  This is how I include my data file in my build.xml

```
<path id ="test.input.dir" >
  <pathelement path="C:\soapTest\atmTest3.csv" />
</path>

<path id="classpath.junittest">
   <path refid="test.input.dir" /> 
   <path refid="jars.dir" />       
</path>
```

My JUNIT method is very basic

```
public void testRunner() throws Exception
{
    SoapUITestCaseRunner runner = new SoapUITestCaseRunner();
    runner.setProjectFile("C:/soapTest/ATM-Locator-soapui-project.xml");
    runner.run();
}
```

Has anyone had success using an external datasource file and running in JUNIT?

Are there alternatives?

------------------  ANT Output below  -------------------

```
Building in workspace C:\JENKINS_PROJECTS\workspace\JUNIT_Test
[JUNIT_Test] $ cmd.exe /C '"C:\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin\ant.bat -D-Verbose="" -D-Debug="" && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
Buildfile: C:\JENKINS_PROJECTS\workspace\JUNIT_Test\build.xml
     [echo] Apache Ant version is Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013 
     [echo] Apache basedir is C:\JENKINS_PROJECTS\workspace\JUNIT_Test 

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to C:\JENKINS_PROJECTS\workspace\JUNIT_Test\classes

compile-test:
    [javac] Compiling 6 source files to C:\JENKINS_PROJECTS\workspace\JUNIT_Test\classes

test:
    [junit] Running com.JUnit.AllTests
    [junit] Testsuite: com.JUnit.AllTests
Unable to obtain resource from C:\soapTest\atmTest3.csv: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    [junit] Unable to obtain resource from C:\soapTest\atmTest3.csv: 
    [junit] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    [junit]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    [junit]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getResourceURL(AntClassLoader.java:1006)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getResource(AntClassLoader.java:887)
    [junit]     at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.getResource(Loader.java:96)
    [junit]     at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:103)
    [junit]     at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:117)
    [junit]     at com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.<clinit>(SoapUI.java:135)
    [junit]     at com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner.<clinit>(SoapUITestCaseRunner.java:79)
    [junit]     at com.util.ParameterATM_Test.testRunner(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    [junit]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    [junit]     at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    [junit]     at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    [junit]     at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    [junit]     at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    [junit]     at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    [junit]     at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
    [junit]     at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
    [junit]     at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    [junit]     at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    [junit]     at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    [junit]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    [junit]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    [junit]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    [junit]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    [junit]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    [junit]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    [junit]     at junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.run(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:39)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:532)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.executeInVM(JUnitTask.java:1425)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:852)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.executeOrQueue(JUnitTask.java:1904)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:804)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    [junit]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ZipException when running junit tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015092/zipexception-when-running-junit-tests)

Comment: That is not a duplicate question it is slightly different.  I have my tests running.  IT is when I try to include a test which has an external data file that I get a zip exception

Comment: please run ant with [the `-debug` option](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html) and add the output to the question

Comment: I have 2 tests running.  The test without an external file for a datasource runs perfectly

Comment: Is this still an issue? How is the test with external datasource finding that file?